# How do I play audio and Video file from same application in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a running code, which can play a audio files from sd card, now I also want to play a video files from same folder. So, the player should be able to play audio or video files in random sequence? The files should play automatically(no interface required) . Please help how to implement in this below code?

Code:-

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Button playButton;
    private MediaPlayer mp;    
    private static final String MAIN_TAG ="ERROR";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         try {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        //final String file_loc= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        //Log.i("location",file_loc);
             ZipFile zip = new ZipFile("/storage/emulated/0/AjeshDocument/sample.zip");

             for(int i=1;i<9;i++){

             ZipEntry entry = zip.getEntry("sample/rihanna_"+i+".mp3");                        
             if (entry != null) {
                 InputStream in = zip.getInputStream(entry);
                 // see Note #3.
                 File tempFile = File.createTempFile("_AUDIO_", ".wav");
                 FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
                 IOUtils.copy(in, out);

                 // do something with tempFile (like play it)
                 File f = tempFile;   
                 try {
                     if (f.exists())
                     {
                         Log.i(MAIN_TAG,"Audio file found!");
                         MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
                         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                         mp.setDataSource(fis.getFD());

                        if (mp.isPlaying() == false) {
                         mp.prepare();
                         //mp.setLooping(false);
                         mp.start();                         
                        // mp.stop();
                         //mp.release();

                         mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                             public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp2) {
                                 mp2.release();

                             };
                         });
                       }  
                         Log.i(MAIN_TAG,"Song finished!");
                     }  


                   else
                     {
                         Log.i(MAIN_TAG,"File doesn't exist!!");
                     }

                 }
                 catch (IOException e)
                 {
                     Log.i(MAIN_TAG,e.toString());
                 }
             }
             else {
                 // no such entry in the zip
             }
            } //for end
            // mp.release();

         }  
             catch (Exception e) {
             // handle your exception cases...

             Log.i(MAIN_TAG,e.toString());

         }       

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.w("Info", "App Resume");

        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.w("Info", "App stopped");

        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.w("Info", "App destoryed");

        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```